# Stacked Div in the same row

Tags: html, css, web

I'm wondering what is the best way to stack a div? Would I be best off using the div class table? Here is my code

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-5 content1">
        [rotatingtweets screen_name='lauterbachgroup']
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 content2">
        <p>Gallery</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 content3">
        <p>content3</p>
    </div>  

        <div class="col-md-5 content4">
            <p>content4</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to get the last content box to flow underneath the first box. I think I may be overthinking it but I have a couple more things I would like to try but, any advice would be great.

Comment: If you want the last div to go under the first one always, you should be using `col-xs-*` instead of `col-md-*`

Comment: I think I may got it, in my CSS I used clear:both to bump it down. But, is that the best way to do it?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro 
How would that work if wanted them to be the same on different sized devices? For say if I used col-xs-6 and col-md-3 because I wanted both divs to perform the same on different sized devices.